# trouble using fstream to read in from file

Tags: c++

I am a beginner trying to code a game project. I have been trying to troubleshoot why my code wont read in from my .txt file with no success. The only problem I can find in the code is that the word from the file won't read in to str.CurrentArea which keeps the game from playing. It opens the file correctly but does not read from it. I tried creating a string directly in main to copy to and it did not work either so the problem isnt with the structure. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define GAME_FILE "escape_the_house.txt"//read in for the world data
#define CONTINUE    1
#define QUIT            0

struct Area{

    string strCurrentArea;

};

void DisplayArea(Area &area);
void GetAreaInfo(ifstream &fin,Area &area);

int main(){

    ifstream fin;//pointer that opens and reads from file
    Area area;//area structure data

    fin.open(GAME_FILE);

    if(fin.fail()){
        cout<<"UNABLE TO FIND GAME FILE\n";

        return 1;
    }
    fin>>area.strCurrentArea>>area.strCurrentArea;//reads in the start point for the game

    GetAreaInfo(fin,area);//calls function to receive info from the file

    DisplayArea(area);//calls function to display the area to the user

    while(1){//main game loop


        if(Input(fin,area)==QUIT){//if user enters quit, game ends
            break;
        }
    }

    fin.close();//closes file

    return 0;
```

Comment: `fin>>area.strCurrentArea>>area.strCurrentArea;` why do you read into the same thing twice? This could be your error.

Comment: I think you need to use std::getline().

Comment: What does `escape_the_house.txt` look like?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I read it in twice so it skips the first world in the .txt and starts from the second. I have looked at that as well. I defined a string in main to read it in to once and then output but it outputs nothing, I don't understand where the problem arises from.

Comment: getline() did not work

   'getline(fin,area.strCurrentArea);
    cout<<area.strCurrentArea;'

Comment: Tip: make a clearly marked junk variable rather than that double read into area.strCurrentArea. It makes following the intent of the code much easier. Eg. `string junk; fin>>junk>>area.strCurrentArea;`

Comment: thet txt file looks like this

<Start> Beginning

<Beginning>
Area Description*
<north> Top
<east>  Right
<south> Bottom
<west>  Left

The program is supposed to skip the first world and read in the second, which it takes to a seperate function that concatenates brackets to the world and searches for it in the file.

Comment: Check for failure after each read to see if the read succeeded. eg. `if(fin>>junk>>area.strCurrentArea) {cout <<"YAY! Got data!";}`

Comment: You keep saying "world", do you mean "word"? The second word is "Beginning", right?. You should be checking the read operation worked correctly e.g. `if (fin >> dummy >> area.strCurrentArea) GetAreaInfo(fin, area); else { cerr << "Error reading area\n"; return 1; }` ... that way your program doesn't just keep going after something fails. (You will also know if it fails to read from the file ... you say that's the problem but how do you know? Have you printed the value of `area.strCurrentArea`?)

Comment: Recommend editing the question to add the file format directly into the question.

Comment: @user4581301, that's fine for debugging, but you don't really want the final program to keep saying "YAY! got data!". Much better is to add checking that stays in the program permanently, so is silent when it succeeds but noisy when it _fails_. The OP's code is silent in both cases, so it tells you nothing.

Comment: @JonathanWakely agreed. Your pitch is the better.

Comment: Thank you everyone, after incorporating the if loops i was able to troubleshoot the problem, the program is working now

Comment: The lesson is: check for errors, don't assume you know what is (or isn't) working